# Does Netty Expose the Number of Connections in the Backlog of the ParentGroup?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

By setting a `ChannelOption` I can specify the backlog size of the queue handling incoming connections.

`.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)`

I want to instrument my code so that I can measure the capacity in the queue. Does Netty provide any means of exposing the current state of the backlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not as it is completely handled within the kernel of your OS.