# Reactor netty http server metrics and connection limit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactor-netty

For reactor netty http server not able to figure-out couple of info :

- How to get max number of http server connection by default and how to modify them ? [Tried going over [this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html) but didn't find proper info]
- How to publish the reactor netty http server connection/event loop lag metrics ? [Tried this but didnt help `management.metrics.enable.reactor.netty.http.server.connections=true`]
- Spring boot starter : 2.3.12
- Reactor netty : 0.9.20

Comment: This version of Reactor Netty is not supported, please upgrade.

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva do you have any idea on default number of connections, is there no limit ?

Comment: are you asking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099270/does-netty-expose-the-number-of-connections-in-the-backlog-of-the-parentgroup

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva i am looking for what is number of max connection netty server will accept and process at any given time, For example tomcat has 10k connection limit : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html, Is this the same ?

Comment: there isn't any